# What can i do if something does not display correctly in HTML

Tags: html, display

can someone please tell me what i can do to check why something in html does not display correctly?
Also how to recognize why something is not displaying and explain how why or where the problem can be?

Comment: Use chrome dev tools. Ctrl + Shift + I in chrome.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow  - [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4q86IjJFag) it's an oldie, but very relevant to what you're trying to find out